# Select cell values inside a Listview - Details View

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, c#-4.0

I am creating Windows Forms application using C# .NET in Visual Studio 2010.

I populate data to a ListView from a Excel file. Now I wanted to select a particular cell or list of adjacent cells vertically. I have attached a sample image here:

[image]

I wanted do something like this inside a ListView.

I need suggestion from you to understand the methodology (like what are events I should use, what properties of the ListView I should change to do this, etc.)

I appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: Is there some particular reason why you need to use a `ListView` control? Otherwise, as Hans suggests, using a [`DataGridView` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) (which you also get for free with WinForms) is the easiest option. It has stuff like this built right in. Look in your Toolbox under the "Data" tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ListView control is a poor substitute for a grid control.  You can simulate this by tinkering with ListViewItem.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false, the sub-item's BackColor property and ListView.HitTest() but that isn't any fun.  Consider DataGridView or one of the many spreadsheet and grid controls available from 3rd party vendors.

Comment: I am thinking now GridView is more suitable for my requirement. Thank You very much. Helps a lot.